# List all MongoDB databases from Linux bash terminal

Tags: mongodb-3.0, linux

Can you list all databases in MongoDB from a linux bash terminal? I cannot find the correct command. I am trying to list all so as that I can write a bash script to backup all DB's individually. Is there a better way?

Comment: See this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947929/how-to-list-all-databases-in-the-mongo-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"show dbs" calculate the databases sizes and that may take some time.

You can pass this command to the mongo shell, then clean the response:

```
echo "db.getMongo().getDBNames()"|mongo --quiet |tr -d \[\] | tr , "\n"|cut -c3-| tr -d \"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit tricky, as built-in command `show dbs` will show databases with sizes. Plus this command cannot be `eval`ed.

However commands can be passed with bash heredoc syntax. And to get rid of sizes, only even values can be displayed.

To skip showing welcome message use `--quiet` option.

Resulting script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $dbs will contain db names and sizes mixed together
# Use --quiet to skip connection information
dbs=$(mongo --quiet <<EOF
show dbs
quit()
EOF
)
i=0
for db in ${dbs[*]}
do
    # Odd values are db names
    # Even values are sizes
    i=$(($i+1))
    # Show db name, ignore size
    if (($i % 2)); then
        echo "$db"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `--eval` parameter

```
mongo --eval 'show dbs'
```

Comment: `mongo --eval 'show dbs'
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.15
connecting to: test
2017-10-12T10:43:10.642+0000 E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`